# Using MIN function in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, min

I have a SQL Query of a view. This view

```
SELECT
  [ID]
  [Name],
  [Category],
  MIN(OrderDate) as OrderDate, 
  MIN(DeliveryDate) as DeliveryDate
GROUP BY
  [ID], [Name], [Category]
FROM
  [OrdersView]
```

I know this query is correct because my DBA gave it to me. But I need to convert it into LINQ. Currently, I have the following:

```
var orders = from o in dataContext.OrdersView
             group o by new { o.ID, o.Name, o.Category } into grouping
             select new Order() {
               ID = grouping.Key.ID,
               Name = grouping.Key.Name,
               Category = grouping.Key.Category,
               OrderDate = ?,
               DeliveryDate = ?
             };
```

My problem is I do not know how to execute the MIN function on the OrderDate and DeliveryDate and use those values in my LINQ query. Unfortunately, I cannot change the database because its locked down. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`OrderDate = grouping.Min(a => a.OrderDate)`

`DeliveryDate = grouping.Min(a => a.DeliveryDate)`

Edit: Used `o` instead of `grouping` accidentally. That should do it for you.

Comment: You may be totally correct since I can't test right now, but does that take the grouping into account?

Comment: Yes; I'm assuming here that the lines I provided will be plugged into the shown code where the question marks are.

Comment: I was remarking on the answer before your change from o to grouping, now it looks alright :)

Comment: Aah, ninja comment :) I always use `group o by o.Whatever into o`, so I just used `o` initially out of habit, haha

Answer (score 1):

```
var orders = from o in dataContext.OrdersView
         group o by new { o.ID, o.Name, o.Category } into grouping
         let orderDate = grouping.Min(order => order.OrderDate)
         let deliveryDate = grouping.Min(order => order.DeliveryDate)
         select new Order() {
           ID = grouping.Key.ID,
           Name = grouping.Key.Name,
           Category = grouping.Key.Category,
           OrderDate = orderDate,
           DeliveryDate = deliveryDate
         };
```

In future I'd recommend to use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for testing your queries. It allows to view generated SQL code.